# Different server pointing to same domain but to different websites

Tags: web-hosting

on Server 1 below are website folder structure

posts/folder1 points to https://example.com/posts/folder1

posts/folder2 points to https://example.com/posts/folder2

On Server 2, folder 3 is a website code

So can posts/folder3 points to https://example.com/posts/folder3

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Are thecservers on the same local  network?

Comment: You used a couple DNS tags. Are you asking if this can be done with DNS?

Comment: @RohitGupta I feel it is a cluster.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller removed DNS tags, as I know that DNS entry are mapping of IP address to domain (https://example.com) and not to sub folders.

Comment: So then what do you mean by "point"?  Do you want a redirect?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller If I make any changes in folder1 the change should show up in this URL  https://example.com/posts/folder1.  Since it is two servers pointing to the same domain but different folders, is it possible to map servers to the same domain but different folders?

Comment: It is a lot easier to use subdomains.  `https://folder1.example.com/` would be a lot easier to make work.  Are you open to that?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller that is not an option. Yes, it would have been easier with subdomain naming, but I am trying to move folder3 which was on server1 to server2 without changing the domain name.

Comment: It wouldn't be changing the domain name. Subdomains are still part of the same domain. You could put a redirect in place from the folder to the subdomain.

Comment: Its not a cluster unless you serve the same content from alternative systems or use a load-balancer/proxy of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

Similar variations of this question have been asked a few times here.

In order to "merge" the contents of 2 servers sharing a single domain name you need to use a reverse proxy. This would mean that all content on server2 will go through server1 (or Vice-Versa) or alternatively you could have a stand alone reverse proxy divvying requests between server 1 and server 2.

This can be achieved using mod_proxy if you are using Apache.  NGINX has similar functionality.

There is no mechanism in common use which allows you to split directories between 2 servers without some kind of reverse proxy or load balancing in common use.   (ie conceptually for the purposes of HTTP/HTTPS a domain resolves to a single IP address = a single Interface on a machine)